# How to profile a silverlight application?

Tags: silverlight, profiling

Is their any profilers that support Silverlight? I have tried ANTS (Version 3.1) without any success? Does version 4 support it? Any other products I can try?

**Updated**
since the release of Silverlight 4, it is now possible to do full profiling on SL applications... check out [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/seema/archive/2010/01/28/pdc-vs2010-profiling-silverlight-4.aspx) article on the topic

> At PDC, I announced that Silverlight 4 came with the new CoreCLR capability of being profile-able by the VS2010 profilers: this means that for the first time, we give you the power to profile the managed and native code (user or platform) used by a Silverlight application. woohoo. kudos to the CLR team.
>
> Sidenote: From silverlight 1-3, one could only use things like xperf (see XPerf: A CPU Sampler for Silverlight) which is very powerful to see the layout/text/media/gfx/etc pipelines, but only gives the native callstack.)

From [SilverLite](http://blogs.msdn.com/seema) ([PDC video, TechEd Iceland, VS2010, profiling, Silverlight 4](http://blogs.msdn.com/seema/archive/2010/01/28/pdc-vs2010-profiling-silverlight-4.aspx))

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Install XPerf and xperfview as available here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc305218.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20140825011849/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/seema/archive/2008/10/08/xperf-a-cpu-sampler-for-silverlight.aspx)

(1) Startup your sample

(2)       xperf -on base

(3)      wait for a bit

(4)       xperf –d myprofile.etl

(5)  when this is done, set your symbol path:

```
set _NT_SYMBOL_PATH= srvC:\symbolshttp://msdl.microsoft.com/downloads/symbols
```

(6) xperfview myprofile.etl

(7) Trace -> Load Symbols

- Select the area of the CPU graph that you want to see
- Right-click and select Summary Table

(8) Accept the EULA for using symbols, expand IExplore, expand agcore.dll or whatever is your top module

Answer (score 6):

Visual Studio 2010 (with the Silverlight 4 tools) comes with command line support for profiling Silverlight apps.

Full instructions for profiling SL4 can be found at: http://www.nachmore.com/2010/profiling-silverlight-4-with-visual-studio-2010/

Comment: NOTE: Only for "Ultimate" version of VS2010 or "Premium" - "Professional" Does NOT have it apparently...

Answer (score 5):

Try JetBrains dotTrace performance profiler.
Here is the detail how to:
http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/NetProf/How+to+profile+silverlight+application

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/seema/archive/2008/10/08/xperf-a-cpu-sampler-for-silverlight.aspx) is a detailed blog entry about using XPerf... Also check out [this](http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/PC06/) video (at PDC) about profiling silverlight!!!

Answer (score 1):

AtoLogic SilverProfiler should work for you. See http://www.atologic.com

Answer (score 1):

SL 4.0 has coreclr etw events. Should be able to diagnose exception,gc, threading and few others using the XPERF and [Perfmonitor](http://bcl.codeplex.com/releases/view/42784) and clr etw. I have [blogged](http://naveensrinivasan.wordpress.com/2010/03/15/undocumented-silverlight-feature-%e2%80%93-etw-tracing/) about this.

FYI using Perfmonitor should be able to provide call-stacks.

ETW is available only in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I like RedGate ANTS. I find it to be a much nicer profiler than dotTrace.